# string match and collapse to a unique record

Tags: awk

I have a file with 8 columns. I have shown here just the col1, col2, col3, col7

```
a  FRNUMBER001  ID1 abcdefgh
a  FRNUMBER001  ID2 abcdefg
b  FRNUMBER003  ID3 lmnopqrs
e  FRNUMBER006  ID7 ablmohuijk
b  FRNUMBER003  ID9 lmnopqrstuvw
```

I would want to collapse the col1 that match and treat it as one entity if col1 is same and if col7 is a subset of the longer string.

output:

```
a  FRNUMBER001  ID1 abcdefgh
b  FRNUMBER003  ID9 lmnopqrstuvw
e  FRNUMBER006  ID7 ablmohuijk
```

would this be a easier thing to do in awk? I can get the counter set in awk to add next line if it is the same using `cnt[$1]++` but my problem is how do I deal with subset scenario in awk, like what syntax to use to indicate subset? Please any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using index function in awk

```
cat ip.txt | awk '{if(index($4,$1)>0)printf("%s\n",$0);}'
```

But i have a doubt with your input. As you say that col1 can be equal to col7 or a subset of col7 then with your input the output should be the following

```
a  FRNUMBER001  ID1 abcdefgh
a  FRNUMBER001  ID2 abcdefg
```

Please correct my understanding

Comment: You should not `cat` data to `awk`, use `awk '{if(index($4,$1)>0)printf("%s\n",$0);}' ip.txt`

Comment: what you say is right. But this is only to explain the logic.

Comment: I know, but many uses this forum to learn how to use this type of tools, and its always good custom to show it the best way :)

Comment: Mr.Raghuram, sorry if I confused you. What I meant was that if col 1 matches with the next row , then look at col 7. is that a subset of the record that matched? then throw me the longer sequence including the rest of that row. So  in the example of the output u demonstrated:

Comment: a  FRNUMBER001  ID1 abcdefgh
a  FRNUMBER001  ID2 abcdefg    you will be giving an output :

Comment: a  FRNUMBER001  ID1 abcdefgh
hope this helps. Sorry my edit on this comment box was not cooperating so I had to clarify your confusion in many comments !

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
$ cat file
a  FRNUMBER001  ID1 abcdefgh
a  FRNUMBER001  ID2 abcdefg
b  FRNUMBER003  ID3 lmnopqrs
e  FRNUMBER006  ID7 ablmohuijk
b  FRNUMBER003  ID9 lmnopqrstuvw
```

```
$ awk 'a[$1]{b[$1]=index($4,a[$1])>0?$0:b[$1];next}{a[$1]=$4;b[$1]=$0}END{for(x in b) print b[x]}' file
e  FRNUMBER006  ID7 ablmohuijk
a  FRNUMBER001  ID1 abcdefgh
b  FRNUMBER003  ID9 lmnopqrstuvw
```

You can pipe the output to `sort` if sorting is a requirement. You will have to change `$4` reference to `$7` since you mentioned it is the 7th column you wish to compare with.

Comment: Thanks this works with the condition I have given. However I have cases where  there are:                                                     a  FRNUMBER001  ID1 abcdefgh
a  FRNUMBER001  ID2 abcdefg

Comment: a  FRNUMBER001  ID1 abcdefgh
a  FRNUMBER001  ID2 abcdefg                                                              a FRNUMBER001  ID11 xvjabcdefgh                                                          In this case the output I get is a FRNUMBER001  ID11 xvjabcdefg. So I guess somehow I should specify the extension can be either end.Sort of like a clustering problem , I guess. It will be nice to get the extensions on both ends and get one long piece of string with one mismatch at least. Any comments?